# Can i use viewmodel factories along with hilt dependency injection?

Tags: kotlin, mvvm, dependency-injection, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

I am using mvvm architecture and injecting the repository in the viewmodel using hilt. There is a variable in the activity (i am getting the variable in the activity through an intent) which i need to pass to the viewmodel and i thought viewmodel factories might help. But how to use it alongside hilt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of hilt implementing any sort of "assisted injection" for viewmodels, like the [assisted injection](https://github.com/square/AssistedInject) library from square. But you can easily manage dynamic data within your viewmodel using this sample from this [google sample](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/GithubBrowserSample/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/github/ui/user/UserViewModel.kt).

```
    fun setLogin(login: String?) {
        if (_login.value != login) {
            _login.value = login
        }
    }
```

with this code you will only update the livedata if the value is null, thus even if the fragment rotates, the data will remain the same.

If you wanna check a slight outdated assisted injection project, I have [this one](https://github.com/chenriquevz/challenge-alpha) in Kotlin.